# Как нарисовать изображение с помощью DrawImage на tabPage, перекрывая кнопки?

Tags: c#, winforms, изображения

Как нарисовать изображение (DrawImage) на tabPage, перекрывая кнопки (button)?

Черные круги (DrawImage on tabPage8_Paint) должны перекрывать кнопки

[image]

то есть, мне требуется, чтобы вышло так

[image]

Мой код

```
Image ussdwait =
        global::SibModem.Properties.Resources.waitpl;

public SibModem() {

    InitializeComponent();

    tabPage8.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(tabPage8_Paint);
    gettime();

    this.SizeChanged += new EventHandler(this.SibModem_Resize);
}

protected void tabPage8_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {

    GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.DrawImage(bg, 0, 0);

    Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(offsetant, 0, w, h);
    g.DrawImage(anten, x, y, srcRect, units);

    Rectangle ussdwaitRect = new Rectangle(offsetussd, 0, 64, 64);
    g.DrawImage(ussdwait, usx, usy, ussdwaitRect, units);
}
```

`button4.SendToBack();` - при таком кнопки всё равно перекрывают изображение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `DrawImage` рисует непосредственно на том контроле, которому принадлежит контекст `Graphics`. После того, как будет обработано событие `Paint`, остальные контролы будут нарисованы поверх, и вы не можете изменить порядок вызовов.

Вы можете представить рисование на контексте как покраску пола, а кнопки — мебелью. Сколько мебель вниз-вверх ни передвигай, ниже пола она не опустится.

Можно было бы добавить прозрачный контрол над кнопкой, но... Мы подходим ко второй проблеме: WinForms ну очень отвратительно поддерживает прозрачность. По сути, прозрачность существует только для форм (то есть окон верхнего уровня), а с наложением контролов всё печально. Есть стиль WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, но он всего лишь заставляет контрол пропускать закраску всего своего прямоугольника, а настоящей прозрачности не происходит. То есть, если добавить прозрачный контрол сверху, то один он, конечно, нарисуется со всеми прозрачностями, но ни передвинуть, ни анимировать это нормально не получится. Есть хак: пересоздавать контрол при каждом чихе.

Такое [решение можно найти на большом СО](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434706/293099):

```
public class TransparentControl : Control
{
    private readonly Timer _refresher;
    private Image _image;

    public TransparentControl ()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        _refresher = new Timer();
        _refresher.Tick += TimerOnTick;
        _refresher.Interval = 50;
        _refresher.Enabled = true;
        _refresher.Start();
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMove (EventArgs e)
    {
        RecreateHandle();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_image != null) {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, (Width / 2) - (_image.Width / 2), (Height / 2) - (_image.Height / 2));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground (PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do not paint background
    }

    //Hack
    public void Redraw ()
    {
        RecreateHandle();
    }

    private void TimerOnTick (object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecreateHandle();
        _refresher.Stop();
    }

    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            return _image;
        }
        set
        {
            _image = value;
            RecreateHandle();
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно, отсюда уже можно плясать.

Ещё есть полноценный альфа-блендинг для дочерних контролов, но он работает, только начиная с Windows 8 или около того (не помню точно), поэтому возможность на данный момент бесполезная.

---

Если вам нужен нормально нарисованный интерфейс с собственными стилями, то посмотрите в сторону WPF. Там и прозрачность, и стилизация работают из коробки, и никаких плясок с бубном не требуется.